# Snap different objects to each other

Tags: snapping

I have this situation: many cubes near to each other.
[image]

Each cube is not perfectly touching each other, because there is some gap between them:
[image]

Is there a way to :
**snap** automatically all the cubes to each other without overlapping, without merging them and without moving every object manually?

Desidered result:
[image]

Comment: Why think backwards tho: just create them properly in the first place.

Comment: Hi radoo, unfortunally I cant create them proberly because the "slice" method that I apply on the model give this little offest!